# Rails SQL efficiency for where statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

Is there a more efficient method for doing a Rails SQL statement of the following code?

It will be called across the site to hide certain content or users based on if a user is blocked or not so it needs to be fairly efficient or it will slow everything else down as well.

**users.rb file:**

```
  def is_blocked_by_or_has_blocked?(user)
    status = relationships.where('followed_id = ? AND relationship_status = ?', 
          user.id, relationship_blocked).first ||
        user.relationships.where('followed_id = ? AND relationship_status = ?', 
          self.id, relationship_blocked).first
    return status
  end
```

In that code, `relationship_blocked` is just an abstraction of an integer to make it easier to read later.

In a view, I am calling this method like this:

```
- unless current_user.is_blocked_by_or_has_blocked?(user)
  - # show the content for unblocked users here
```

**Edit**

This is a sample query.. it stops after it finds the first instance (no need to check for a reverse relationship)

```
Relationship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE ("relationships".follower_id = 101) AND (followed_id = 1 AND relationship_status = 2) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Is relationship_blocked essentially "true" or "false", or do you have additional states (0, 1, 2, 3...) which it can occupy?

Comment: Also, when you display this view, in your log file (e.g. development.log, if you're in the "development" environment) you should see the full SQL statement. How many milliseconds is it currently taking to run, out of curiosity?

Comment: @normalocity: It can occupy one of a few integer states.  It typically takes 0.1 - 0.2ms to run the statement, but that's on a database without many records.  All of the columns it is searching are indexed, so it's more the efficiency of the statement that will be the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it to only run one query by making it use an `IN (x,y,z)` statement in the query (this is done by passing an array of ids to :followed_id). Also, by using `.count`, you bypass Rails instantiating an instance of the model for the resulting relationships, which will keep things faster (less data to pass around in memory):

```
def is_blocked_by_or_has_blocked?(user)
  relationships.where(:followed_id => [user.id, self.id], :relationship_status => relationship_blocked).count > 0
end
```

---

*Edit - To get it to look both ways;*

```
Relationship.where(:user_id => [user.id, self.id], :followed_id => [user.id, self.id], :relationship_status => relationship_blocked).count > 0
```

Comment: How would this be able to check the reverse relationship though? For instance, right now this would only check if `current_user` (or whatever user you're calling the method on) had a relationship that either included himself or the other user, but you'd need to check the reverse of that as well i.e. `user.relationships.where...`

Comment: ah, ok, I didn't notice that in your example. Still, if the first query returns nil, it will end up running the second query. I guess it depends how important that is to you. You could still get around it and turn it into a single query by running a similar query to my example directly on `Relationship` rather than `relationships` or `user.relationships` and just pass more into it (`.where(:user_id => [user.id, self.id])`).